# Set DNS differently per user profile on Mac OS

Tags: macos, dns, parental-controls

Is there a method to set DNS differently according to the user account on Mac OS?

The use case is I want my kids' user accounts on my Mac to use a filtered DNS provider, but for my profile I don't want to use the filtering.

It appears that MacOS (Catalina 10.15.5) sets DNS on a systemwide basis currently -- if I change it in my account, it changes in my kids' accounts, and vice-versa.

I presume there might have to be some sort of Applescript or Automator solution to setting the DNS. I've found some solutions to that, but I'm not sure how to trigger an Applescript based on fast user changing events.